# Navigation Drawer toolbar is not visible on samsung skin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I have a navigation drawer activity which works fine but when I run it on Samsung s3 and such it just not showing the tool bar above but if I drag from the side it will open the drawer, I read that it is something about Samsung skin but I couldn't find a way to fix it..
How can I create a navigation drawer toolbar that will work the same and show on the Samsung skin.

here is the app_bar_main:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.nightme.nightme.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#14418a"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
             >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:text="App"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_paint"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/rec_activity" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are saying that the toolbar icon with 3 lines that opens the navigation drawer is not showing up?

That icon is setup by the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class. You have to create it in your Activity's onCreate as shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon

Comment: No the whole toolbar is not showing instead of a toolbar it just showing white rect.

Comment: Not sure what is causing the white rectangle to show up. Here's a guide on how to implement the navigation drawer, you could check it to make sure you've taken the necessary steps: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer